# Which phtml is used for displaying the results of searched products

Tags: magento2

To display the result of the searched products(CatalogSearch), which phtml template is getting called.

I need to place that phtml file in my custom theme for overriding the same.

I belv it is result.phtml

Answer (score 1):

The file is `vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/view/frontend/templates/result.phtml`

There are a few ways you can find out which file creates a page.

1. Turn on path hints (`Store > Configuration > Advanced > Developer > Debug > Enabled Template Path Hints for Storefront > Yes`)
2. Look at the class of `<body>` to get the controller file. By reading the code you can easily figure out the template.
   [image]
   As you can see from the image above, the body of the result page has a class of `catalogsearch-result-index`. Which tells us that the module `catalog-search` is responsible for the page.

Answer (score 0):

This phtml template is used for displaying the results of searched products:

**vendor\magento\module-catalog-search\view\frontend\templates\result.phtml**

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed

> /vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/view/frontend/templates/result.phtml

However for the actual product listing this then uses the same template as the standard catalog.